# asp.net - Close server-side form after submit postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a form with the runat="server" attribute set. (This is not the main form on the page)

It is inside a div which is hidden by default.

Using jQuery I show it on a click event of another button.

When the form is submitted the postback happens and I want to hide the div again if the postback completed without errors.
If there was a validation error, I want to leave the form visible and the server-side code handles showing the correct error.

What I'm missing is how to tie in the postback return to the jQuery handler to re-hide the form.
One idea I had was using a hidden form field, but I would rather find a more elegant solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot just set the Visibility to false in your server side code ?

Comment: For some reason doing this server-side didn't even cross my mind :) Thank you! Care to add an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply set the Visibility to False on the server side :-)

Comment: One little caveat I will mention with this approach is that you can't un-hide it from script later, since elements with Visible=false are not rendered into the DOM at all. Not a problem in my case.

Comment: You are comrrect Elad - a way around that would be to set a "style='display:none;'" attribute on the element from sever side code - that way you can modify it with script later on. Or even a CssClass with display:none;